# Making Figure-8 into a manifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, intuition

So I am using the map in Lee's Smooth manifold book $\beta(t) = (\sin 2 t, \sin t)$. This is an injective immersion where $t \in (-\pi, \pi).$

Now the image is not a manifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ because an open ball around near the origin gives a picture of "X" and that doesn't look like $\mathbb{R}$?

1. Can we make it a 1-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^2$? Or would that require the "X" to look like $\mathbb{R}$? Which is not possible.
2. Is that the problem with self-intersections on $\mathbb{R}^2$? Because it would create pictures like "X" or "$\bot$" and those don't look like $\mathbb{R}$?

Next, I've been told that if we look use the induced topology by $\beta$ from $(-\pi, \pi)$, this can be made into a manifold (of $\mathbb{R}$?)

3.Even if I look near $0$ with an open interval in the image set, I am still going to get an "X" shape no? Or do they mean that if I delete the intersection point, a neighborhood near the center would "ignore" the other three pieces of the "X"?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The key idea here is that switching to a different topology on the same set changes the meaning of "near" and "neighborhood".

I'll call the set of points in the image of $\beta$ by the name $\Theta$ (it's the eighth letter of the Greek alphabet and looks slightly like a numeral 8 too).

At first, we're looking at the topology induced by the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ on $\Theta$. So an open set of $\Theta$ is the intersection of  any open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\Theta$, and we can use the intersections of the open balls of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as basic neighborhoods within $\Theta$.

> Now the image is not a manifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ because an open ball around near the origin gives a picture of "X" and that doesn't look like $\mathbb{R}$?

On terminology - "A manifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$" doesn't mean much. What I'd say is if it weren't for the point $(0,0)$, $\Theta$ with this topology would be a 1-manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$. "Around near the origin" sounds like something you might not mean: Note that any point in $\Theta$ near, but not equal to, the origin *is* in an open set diffeomorphic to an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$. Only the origin itself is a problem. But yes, since the intersection of any open ball of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\Theta$ "looks like an X" and is not like a curve, there is no open set in $\Theta$ containing the origin diffeomorphic to an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$, and $\Theta$ cannot be a 1-manifold. This could be proved more formally, but that's a good intuitive idea of it.

But now when we switch to the topology induced by $\beta$, the meaning of "near" and "neighborhood" changes.

> Even if I look near $0$ with an open interval in the image set, I am still going to get an "X" shape no? Or do they mean that if I delete the intersection point, a neighborhood near the center would "ignore" the other three pieces of the "X"?

There is no point deletion involved here, but we do need to pay attention to the neighborhoods used. Now an open set of $\Theta$ is the image $\beta \big((a,b)\big)$ of any open interval $(a,b) \subseteq (-\pi,\pi)$. A small open set of $\Theta$ around the origin, like $\beta\big( (-\delta,\delta) \big)$, includes only the origin and portions in the first and third quadrants, and that set is curve-like. In fact, it has an obvious chart onto $\mathbb{R}$: $\beta^{-1}$ maps this open set back to the original open interval $(-\delta,\delta) \subset \mathbb{R}$. The "tails" in the second and fourth quadrants aren't actually "near" the origin, in the sense that an open set including the origin is not forced to include them.

Comment: Are the two arrows in the image not touching and crossing each other? Because I don't quite understand your last sentence. Are you saying an open set in the image of $\beta$ for the "tails" is just "- -"?

Comment: In the topology induced by $\beta$, there are open sets like $\beta \big( (-\pi, -\pi+\delta) \big)$ in the second quadrant on one of the tails, open sets like $\beta \big( (\pi-\delta, \pi) \big)$ in the fourth quadrant on the other tail, and open sets like $\beta \big( (-\delta, \delta) \big)$ in the first and third quadrants on the center part. So this topology is exactly like an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$. Since open sets don't relate those three pieces together, it's as if we can "unbend" the almost-touching shape into a shape clearly not touching.

Comment: I think i see what's going on here. But a small (irrelevant) correction first. I think $\beta( -\pi, -\pi+\delta)$ corresponds to the fourth quadrant and $\beta( \pi - \delta, \pi-\delta ) $ corresponds to the second quadrant. Essentially, the open intervals (the open sets induced by $\mathbb{R}$) in $(-\pi,pi)$ in the image of $\beta$ are segments that don't "see" the other tails and that locally looks like an open interval, and that is euclidean, so it is a manifold under this topology.

Comment: You're correct about the quadrants, and I agree with that explanation.

Comment: When we say topology induced by $\beta$ such as this case, a $U$ set is open in the image $\beta$ if and only if $\beta^{-1}(U)$ is open in $(-pi, pi)$?